# How to get image with its name and any extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html, vb.net

I am building an asp.net website.  I want to show image on the page, but while I know the image name, I don't know the extension.

So, I want to open the images directory and get the image by its name whatever its extension.

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? What did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Directory object to get a list of file in a directory

```
string imageFilename = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( imageDirectory, name + ".*" ).First();
```

Comment: It's pretty much a matter of taste, but I'd rather use ' name + ".*" ' in stead of concat function. Same end result, but more readable.

Comment: It gave me this error: "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path."

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path." occurs when you haven't escaped the '\' character try "C:\\" or @"C:\"

Comment: DJ Pirtu, string.Concat is a habit, our work coding style requires it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how files work -- you need to know the whole name. For example, what happens if there's multiple images with the same base name and different extensions? Compare `foo.png` and `foo.jpg`, for example.

One suggestion is to try doing a wildcard search on all files with some base name in that directory (that's what bstoney's solution does; [**see here**](http://#658317)). If you find exactly one match, you're done. If you get multiple matches, you'll need to make rules about which one wins.